# Can install4j 6 running on Linux correctly codesign an OS X app bundle?

Tags: install4j

I've installed install4j 6 on Linux. It creates and signs my OS X app bundle and creates a DMG. But whenever I open the DMG and run the created app inside, Gatekeeper says it is from an unidentified developer.

```
> codesign -vv /Volumes/pokercopilot/Poker\ Copilot.app
/Volumes/pokercopilot/Poker Copilot.app: unsupported resource found (something not a directory, file or symlink)
```

When I run the same install4j build on OS X, the app bundle is correctly signed.

```
 > codesign -vv Poker\ Copilot.app/
 Poker Copilot.app/: valid on disk
 Poker Copilot.app/: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

I'm trying to eliminate factors, and want to check that what I'm attempting is within the capability of install4j.

Update: install4j has created a file with an invalid filename:

```
cp -rf /Volumes/pokercopilot/Poker\ Copilot.app .
cp: /Volumes/pokercopilot/Poker Copilot.app/Contents/Resources/app/.install4j/icons/.install4j/${compiler:pcp.productShortName}Updater.icns: No such file or directory
```

It seems a variable reference hasn't been replaced with the value it has been assigned. When I use install4j on OS X, the folder ./Contents/Resources/app/.install4j/icons/.install4j/ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The code that signs the DMG is pure Java code without any external dependencies, so the operating system on which install4j is executed does not matter for this purpose.

> When I run the same install4j build on OS X, the app bundle is correctly signed.

Since you did not download the DMG, it is not checked by gatekeeper. Probably the signature is invalid here as well. To check if the signature is valid, execute

```
codesign -vv application.app
```

One probable cause for an invalid signature is that you did not use the "Developer ID Application" certificate for signing.

**Update:**

This is actually a bug in install4j introduced by the fact that ICNS icons are now automatically compiled from cross-platform images. This only happens if you use compiler variables in the "Executable name" property of an installer application. This bug will be fixed in 6.0.1.

Workaround: In the "Executable icon" property of the installer application (the updater in this case), select "Use ICNS file" in the "Mac OS X" section and choose the file `[instal4j installation directory]/resource/macos/app.icns`.

Comment: when I wrote "the app bundle is correctly signed", I meant that I used codesign to verify. I'll update the question with the output of codesign on both app bundles.

Comment: OK, so pcp.productShortName is not replaced in your Linux build

Comment: Yes, that's right. But only in that one folder, it seems. Otherwise, the app seems fine.

Comment: So where exactly did you enter ${compiler:pcp.productShortName}Updater.icns in your project?

Comment: In install4j 5, in "Installer" -> "Updater without version check" -> "Executable" -> "Executable name" is set to ${compiler:pcp.productShortName}Updater. Then I updated to install4j 6 by loading the config in the GUI and saving again.

Comment: If it helps, I can send you my install4j config file in either version 5 or version 6 format.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit. Please contact me at support@ej-technologies.com for an interim build that contains the fix.